# IAP purchase failed on device, but success on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

On iPhone simulator, I could go through and successfully finished IAP.

However, on my device, It would return at switch-case "SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed" and failed to purchase. Even I deleted the app and tried again, it still does not work. The error msg(transaction.error.localizedDescription) is: "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Apple is having some problems with their servers, Game Center and IAP work really bad right now.

Comment: Why it is OK now on simulator?

Comment: As I said, Apple is having some problems, meaning that it sometimes work and sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are logged in to a *production* App Store account, and that prevents your app from completing an IAP from the *sandbox* environment.

You have to logout of your account. Go to your device Settings -> iTunes & App Stores, tap your ID and logout. Then launch your App through Xcode. When you perform an IAP, the *sandbox* App Store login window should come up. You can login there with any Test User previously created on iTunes Connect.

Answer (score -1):

It is a temporary problem with Apple servers. Recently there were various problems with Game Center (often returning error 404) and In-App Purchases returning "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" and sometimes even proceeding with the transaction afterwards.  Try it multiple times, it will work (if you have your code right of course).